# RestKit Oauth 2 Google API

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, restkit, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get access to the Google Drive API using RestKit on iOS but I'm having problems with the Oauth authentification.

I've been following the Wiki page they have on the subject here:
[Oauth Support On RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/OAuth-Support-on-RestKit)

Basically we create the client like this:

```
oauthClient = [RKClientOAuth clientWithClientID:[Client Id] secret:[Client Secret] delegate:[Your Delegate]];
[oauthClient setAuthorizationCode:[User Authorization Code]];
[oauthClient setAuthorizationURL:[Authorization Endpoint]];
[oauthClient setCallbackURL:[Your application callbackurl]];
[oauthClient validateAuthorizationCode];
```

And we receive an access token on the delegate in the method

```
- (void)OAuthClient:(RKOAuthClient *)client didAcquireAccessToken:(NSString *)token
```

Here we can create an ObjectManager to make the requests and all the other operations

```
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
objectManager.client.baseURL = @"YOUR API URL";
objectManager.client.OAuth2AccessToken = @"YOUR ACCESS TOKEN";
objectManager.client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeOAuth2;
```

With all this I have encountered a few problems.

- First is how do we obtain the authorization code needed here:

  ```
  [oauthClient setAuthorizationCode:[User Authorization Code]];
  ```

  I haven't had problems with Client Id, Client Secret, Authorization Endpoint, Callback URL and API URL as they are provided mostly in the google console API but I don't know how to obtain that.
- Second is the Access Token would be a temporal Access Token or a Refresh Token as they are named in the google API? If it's the first, how can we obtain a Refresh Token?

I've been trying to do this with RestKit but there may be better ways so I'm open to other ideas. I can't find much information about Oauth support in Restkit.

Thanks beforehand

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? I came across this exact same problem while working with Restkit. Honestly I am really confused since the wiki makes it sound like I need to provide authorization code in the first request. However as far as I know, Oauth2 works by the auth server responding with authorization code in response to the first request, which is then used in the second request to finally acquire the access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google's Objective-C client library for the Drive API, including OAuth 2 sign-in.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Answer (score 4):

You must use Google ObjectiveC Library in order to access Google Drive APi.
https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios

Answer (score 0):

You start with your client ID and client secret, you direct the user to the resource owner's authorization server. The authorization server and the user validate each other and your app is returned an Authorization Code. You go back to the authorization server and exchange the Authorization Code for an Access Token.

If the Access Token is time boxed, then you would use the Refresh Token to request a new Access Token when you discover that the Access Token has timed out.